# how to make json format php array and how to get the json srting values

Tags: php, codeigniter

here i have one array in this array i want to make json,i tried but i am unable to get the exact format what i want,any one please help me,

### This my array

> var_dump($absentresponse);

```
     array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["absendId"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["studentAbsentId"]=>
    string(9) "["1","2"]"
    ["studentAbsentDate"]=>
    string(10) "2017-04-11"
    ["schoolId"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["classId"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["sectionId"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["reg_date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-04-13 01:01:03"
    ["created_by"]=>
    string(29) "kanniyappan@g2evolution.co.in"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

> My expected results

```
    {
    "status": 1,
    "data": 
    [
    {
      "studentabsentId":"1"
      "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-12"
    },
    {
      "studentabsentId":"2"
      "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-12"
    }
    ]
}
```

### My Update Code

> $json_response = json_encode($absentresponse);        echo $json_response;

```
    [
  {
    "absendId": "1",
    "studentAbsentId": "[\"1\",\"2\"]",
    "studentAbsentDate": "2017-04-11",
    "schoolId": "2",
    "classId": "1",
    "sectionId": "1",
    "reg_date": "2017-04-13 01:01:03",
    "created_by": "kanniyappan@g2evolution.co.in",
    "status": "0"
  }
]
```

Comment: How do you encode your json ?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some wrong format in your array. Please recheck on index `studentAbsentId`, I think that should be an `array`, not a string. Below is my code if we assume that value of `studentAbsentId` is an array of student ID.

```
    $newArray = array();
    $newArray['status'] = $absentresponse['status'];
    $newArray['data'] = array();
    foreach($absentresponse['studentAbsentId'] as $id){
        $data['studentabsentId'] = $id;
        $data['studentAbsentDate'] = $absentresponse['studentAbsentDate'];
        $newArray['data'][] = $data;
    }

    $json = json_encode($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $absentresponse = array();
    $data['status'] = 1;
    foreach ($absentresponse as $key => $value) {
        $row = array();
        $row['absendId'] = $value['absendId'];
        $row['studentAbsentId'] = $value['studentAbsentId'];
        $row['studentAbsentDate'] = $value['studentAbsentDate'];
        $row['schoolId'] = $value['schoolId'];
        $row['classId'] = $value['classId'];
        $row['sectionId'] = $value['sectionId'];
        $row['reg_date'] = $value['reg_date'];
        $row['created_by'] = $value['created_by'];
        $data['data'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
    $json_response = json_encode($absentresponse);
    echo $json_response;
```

Comment: I tried your code but i am not getting my expected results,please check my updated code and answer

Comment: please see my expected results ,  i need like that json format using $absentresponse array

Answer (score -2):

```
$absentresponse_json = json_encode($absentresponse);
```

Unless I'm not understanding your question, that should do it.

Comment: I tried your code but i am not getting my expected results,please check my updated code and answer